# Eliminating multiple delimiters in single column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has single column info

```
Info
```

+aname + + + + + + +ano+ + + + + + + + + +agender+ + + + + + + + + + + +  +arace

I should get output like

```
aname+ano+agender+arace
```

I have to eliminate multiple delimiters and replace with single `+`
I tried with regexp_replace and trim and working as below

```
    select trim(REGEXP_REPLACE('+aname + + + + + + +  
+ano + + + + + + + +   
+agender+ + + + + + + + + + +   
+arace', '\ + + ', '+'),'+') from dual;
```

i get output as 
aname+++++++ano+++++++agender++++++++++arace

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: But why do you store data like that? That's your major issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regexp does the trick: '\++'

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('+aname++++++ano+++++++++agender++++++++++++arace', '\++', '+') from dual;
```

To get rid of the leading + (like in your example), use ltrim (or trim to remove trailing + too).

```
select ltrim(REGEXP_REPLACE('+aname++++++ano+++++++++agender++++++++++++arace', '\++', '+'),'+') from dual;
```

Comment: Hi the solution worked, thank you..however I tried with space ' ' between the plus and in replace I done as '\ + + ,'+' it eliminates all spaces and replace with '+' , I dont want multiple + there and also if i take line break while writing query as '+aname+++(in the newline)+ano+++++(in the newline again) +agender' the output shows as aname++ano++agender.  May i know the reason why

Comment: @ramya: Can you edit your question to make that issue you have with spaces and line breaks more clear? If not, consider asking another question.